# How to I resize fluid image from "gatsby-image" on my index.js page in gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have been trying to resize the image on my index.js page in my Gatsby project. I have it loaded through the "gatsby-image" import, and all my code as it should be, but I cant figure out how to resize on both that js file, or the scss file I made for styling.

I have tried to change the maxWidth size, but all that seems to do is change the actual image quality, and not the size. I have also tried to change it in the scss file, but that doesnt seem to work either.

```
<Img fluid={props.data.imageOne.childImageSharp.fluid} />

export const fluidImage = graphql`
  fragment fluidImage on File {
   childImageSharp {
    fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
     }
   }
  }
`;

export const pageQuery = graphql`
 query {
  imageOne: file(relativePath: { eq: "me.jpg" }) {
  ...fluidImage
   }
 }
`
```

I am expecting the image to be smaller, but the only output I have had at the moment is a lower quality image, or parts of the image being chopped off.

Comment: To feed file data in to Gatsby Image, set up a GraphQL query and either pass it into a component as props or write it directly in the component. One technique is to leverage the useStaticQuery hook.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot change the `maxWidth: 1000` directly in the query via a variable because GraphQL runs once at build time and then never again. No hot reloading possible.

```
export const fluidImage = graphql`
  fragment fluidImage on File {
   childImageSharp {
    fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
     }
   }
  }
`;
```

GraphQL delivers the image to you in the quality you specify. You can then resize the image via CSS. I remember having the same problem as you. I wrapped the image component in a div that has a defined `with` or `min-width / max-width`. Not the most elegant solution but it works.

```
import GatsbyImage from "gatsby-image";
// ...
<ImageWrapper className="imageWrapper">
  <GatsbyImage fluid={fluid} />
</ImageWrapper>
```

In your CSS file:

```
.imageWrapper {
   /*   min-width: 11rem; */
   /*   max-width: 20rem; */
   width: 280px;
}
```